# Laptop in hand luggage with qatar airways from UK to india

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items, hand-luggage, security, packing

I want to take my laptop as I need to its related to my work. However it will not fit in my hand luggage it is heavy (HP pavillion g6). And I've been searching online and a lot of people have said they get stolen if you put it in checked luggage. And I tried looking for hand baggage in accordance to qatar dimensions but I just can't find any. Am I able carry the laptop in my laptop bag over my shoulder? And if I do carry it in checked baggage do I have to take it out or anything? What could I do so I can take my laptop with me and prevent the risks of anything bad happening.

Comment: Also note that the dimensions of your laptop are well within the cabin luggage dimensions of qatar, I find it hard you would not find a suitable bag/suitcase for onboard, at least when taking the laptop out of its case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can bring laptops on board, and yes, full-service airlines like Qatar will let you bring a laptop bag in addition to your carry-on item.

Do **not** check in your laptop: not only is there a risk of theft, but it can easily break, get water damage, etc.

Comment: I used to be convinced that one can not check laptops but apparently it is just a very bad idea. +1

Comment: Hi I checked on the qatar airlines website it said that the laptop has to fit in the hand baggage and mine does not so if I decide to carry it in a laptop bag won't they say to put it in the hand baggage won't there be a problem if I carry my laptop in my laptop bag in my hand as well as carrying my hand luggage in my hand. As I heard that qatar allows only one piece hand luggage and not 2 and Inc laptop bag it would be 2 pc

Comment: @mts Aside from the damage issues, I really don't like the idea of many large Li-ion batteries in checked luggage, but apparently it is permitted. Until something happens to cause the regulations to be re-written I guess.

Comment: @IramAhmed It's usually one 'personal item' which could be your laptop plus the hand luggage. If you're not carrying a purse you should be okay.

Comment: @spehro  pefhany hi yes it does say that but it says small brief case and my laptop dimensions are 15 x 9.5 x 1.6 inch would this be classed as small?

Comment: @IramAhmed  yes .. They want to exclude those suitcases on wheels..

Comment: @ Sphero Pefhany oh you mean they don't like those briefcases with wheels? If so then I'm not taking one of those it just a laptop bag/case with a shoulder strap